# OneSpan SDK DeviceBinding swift iOS

Tags: ios, swift

I need to updated OneSpan SDK - Device Binding but not sure how to pass bundle id and team id.

any help.

passing bundle id and getting Access denied Error.  i have multiple bundle team id and bundle id.

I gone through the documentation but it's bit confusing.